# Android image caching - hard and soft HashMaps question

Tags: android, caching, bitmap, hashmap, soft-references

What I'm trying to do right now within my app is modify the [ImageDownloader](http://code.google.com/p/android-imagedownloader/source/browse/trunk/src/com/example/android/imagedownloader/ImageDownloader.java) class that Google put out last year in one of their tutorials that asynchronously downloads and caches images for ImageViews without leaking the context.

In other words, since I'm using a global cache singleton object which provides references to my Bitmap HashMaps, I just need to know: since I have to cache images separately depending on certain aspects of my app (client requirement), should I have pairs of hard and soft HashMaps for each of those types of Bitmaps, or would it be more efficient to have only one soft HashMap in which the other hard caches move their files to when they are pressed for space?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar problem on an app we worked on. We hard cache images we pull in an SQLite blob. The wrapper will check the cache's existance, or go pull over the network, so even if someone clears the app data, it'll work (a bit slower until images are cached again). Since it's in SQLite the app data can easily be moved around to the SD card and back without having to worry about file paths being changed.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using something like:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>> image_cache =
newConcurrentHashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>>( 1 );
```

For the memory portion of your cache.  The SoftReference's will be garbage collected as the device needs memory.  This will allow your application to keep as many images in memory as possible without causing memory issues.

You can choose to back this cache with a file cache either on the SD card with a root path using:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

or using the cache space provided by android using a path of:

```
context.getCacheDir();
```

The cache space is private whereby the SD card images could be retrieved by a user or modified by a 3rd party program.  The cache space is on the internal storage of the device and it shows up in the application manager statistics.  The user can also clear this cache easily from their settings->application manager screen.

You will need to fill in the algorithm that checks the memory cache first, checks the soft reference if found, checks the file system if not found, and then finally fetches from the network, saves to a file, and puts it in the memory cache.  You can then add additional requirements for the cache based on your client requirements on top of this structure.

Comment: I'm actually soft-referencing the Bitmaps in the soft cache, when the hard cache runs out of space, it sends the oldest one to soft. Plus, the algorithm from that class is practically the same, said for the final check against SD for the image before giving up.

Comment: Why are you trying to managing space at all for images?  The VM can make better decisions about how much memory is available for in memory images.  I'd recommend only have a soft memory cache and use the file system to persist images in case they are forced out of memory but needed again.

Comment: That's the thing, won't soft-references get aggressively GC'd to the point where you need a hard cache that keeps a set amount or images at a time, since you have to presume that the user will run multiple apps concurrently other than mine, thus any one of them can reclaim memory from my app? Even the file system cache will have a limit, It's not like I'm gonna create a unbound hard cache, it'll remove the oldest entry once it hits it max entry limit and stuff it to an unbound soft cache, which the VM can do what it wants with it for all I care.

Comment: Yea, I understand your concerns.  My point is that the VM can set a better limit than you can when you try to determine what the proper hard limit should be for your cache.  If the soft cache is aggressively GC'd, then you wouldn't have room for a fixed hard cache anyway. Another point:  Be sure you are doing these caching activities as the images are displayed, not before they are needed.  If you need to have images available before they are needed, then fetch them to disk in the background, but load them into the soft cache as they are viewed on screen.

Comment: One more thing, since I understand how to set it up now, I am wondering if I should convert ImageDownloader into a singleton with a state machine that switches to the appropriate cache objects as well as my File reader/writer object, or just leave it as is, while still setting states to load up my cache objects. I'm worried if I take the singleton route, if I switch the state of my local caller copy, it will update that single instance accordingly thus the next calling class won't be saving or reading from the appropriate caches?

Comment: I would certainly make your cache infrastructure a singleton.  I would then access the appropriate cache per image request, setting the state as needed.  I've not found that I need to set the state explicitly as the image is either in memory, on disk, or neither.

Comment: My cache object is already a singleton. However, I am trying to see if I should convert the routines that download, save, cleanup, and recover my images from cache into a singleton. In other words, if ImageDownloader is a singleton, that means I would have to switch the appropriate cache objects when getting the instance. So if I had one activity using that class to download ListView thumbnails and then open out an activity on top of it to fetch an image for an ImageView, wouldn't my singletoned ImageDownloader start saving to that cache of the child activity instead of the ones for thumbnails

Comment: So what you're saying is that every time I call my function to fetch images, I should assign a cache state (int or enum), and based on that current state, it would reference the appropriate cache when downloading or pulling images from cache? I dunno if that will work, since I have functions that for example purge the cache after idling out for a set amount of time. If one activity calls the download function for a particular cache, and then another on top of it calls that same function, the last caller will have its cache purged since it set the current cache state.